# Difference between SQL keywords

Tags: sql

I have just started with SQL and want to clear the basic keywords of SQL.
What is the difference between

1. "number" and "numeric" & "number & integer"?
2. While creating a table

```
Create table myTable
(
    my_Id int(6) primary key
...
```

> Above query Gives me an error suggesting to put null or not null before "primary key".

Do I always need to put either null or not null for the keyword integer?

If I replace int(6) with number(6), that statement works.

Comment: You should add a tag for the RDMS you are using, e.g. MySQL, SQL Server. Each has its differences.

Comment: Go to the documentation of what ever you are using. It will give a detailed description of the data types.

Comment: @sayani, a primary key is automatically NOT NULL. (At least in ANSI SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

> 1."number" and "numeric" & "number & integer"?

An integer cannot take inputs such as 1.1 and the likes since float or decimal datatype handles this, while a number can take this both. I believe the reason why INT does not display it with a decimal its because its being rounded off  try to input a 1.5 on an int column and you'll get a 2 instead

> 2.While creating a table
>
> Create table myTable (
>
> my_Id int(6) primary key, <--- Gives me an error suggesting to put
>   null or not null before "primary key". Do I always need to put either
>   null or not null for the keyword integer?

you need to either put a null or not null before a primary key **unless** I believe its been set into an Auto Increment

BTW my answer was based on **MYSQL** since that's what I used.. although I'm not sure if your using it since you didn't add any tags :)

for more info for this topic I think this could add a little more light to your inquiry

[reference link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/926043)

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL a primary key has to be a non-null value ie you will have to indicate by typing in NOT NULL You can re-write the code as follows:

```
my_id INT([optional]) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

> When you want to make a `Primary Key` field it shouldn't be `Null`.

And

> When you use `int` data type it don't have any `(<value>)`, But `number` has.

SO

```
 my_Id int not null primary key
```